# How do you convert decimal in integer to hexadecimal in integer?

Tags: c++, c, binary, hex

```
cout<<std::hex<<dec;
```

I want to store it to an int in the form of 0x...

How do I store that value in an integer instead of printing it out?

Comment: That makes no sense. At all.

Comment: Uhm... what are you trying to do again? In English please.

Comment: Please go read this, then come back with a question that is understandable - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: `int i = 0xF;` and `int i = 15;` both do the exact same thing.

Comment: An `int` has no defined visual representation -- you can choose to present it visually as hex, binary, octal, decimal, or anything else you can think of.  The "visualization" of it occurs when it's printed/displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an integer value, and you want to print it just do the following (in C):

```
int number = 555;
printf("%d",number); //this prints number in decimal

printf("%x",number); //this prints number in haxadecimal
```

You must not forget, to a machine, there are only 0's and 1's.
You just have to define the way you want to print it

In C++:

```
int number = 555;
std::cout << std::hex << number << std::endl; //this will print the number in hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the value into a string stream first:

```
#include <stringstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << dec;

int n;
ss >> n;
```